# Embed URL to coordinates, kml or geojson

Tags: php, google-maps, google-maps-embed

I've got a complex directions URL and embed URL that I would like to get polylines for. Once I can get them into polylines or something similar I can convert to final format: GeoJSON.

[Direction Link](https://www.google.com/maps/dir/Guilford+Welcome+Center/43.3893165,-72.4077225/130+Lower+Michigan+Road,+Pittsfield,+VT+05762/''/Jay+Peak+Resort/Dolly+Copp+Campground+Rd,+Gorham,+NH+03581/Mt+Washington+Auto+Road,+1+Mount+Washington+Auto+Road,+Gorham,+NH+03581/Mt+Washington/Wells,+ME/Libby's+Oceanside+Camp,+York+Street,+York,+ME/@43.8750543,-72.8191003,338155m/am=t/data=!3m2!1e3!4b1!4m59!4m58!1m5!1m1!1s0x0:0xa58b3d6041ba69f8!2m2!1d-72.5661469!2d42.8120069!1m0!1m5!1m1!1s0x4cb52e78df455c83:0xb6946ec850907db8!2m2!1d-72.815214!2d43.76898!1m5!1m1!1s0x0:0xea2de48bba82cc86!2m2!1d-72.6046997!2d44.042544!1m5!1m1!1s0x0:0x6bb602ed58bf4413!2m2!1d-72.5045433!2d44.9379515!1m5!1m1!1s0x4cb392aaa4333a07:0x160aef1559868340!2m2!1d-71.2183734!2d44.3358422!1m5!1m1!1s0x4cb392684201a94d:0xfa4a6f490a05429d!2m2!1d-71.224596!2d44.2883841!1m5!1m1!1s0x4cb38e798f42c3d9:0xc3b88e4dac01db12!2m2!1d-71.3032723!2d44.2705854!1m5!1m1!1s0x89e2a7fa444124d5:0xe3ed24b6f864eba0!2m2!1d-70.5805209!2d43.3222329!1m5!1m1!1s0x89e2ba813e828c71:0x8cdf74380f6a933d!2m2!1d-70.626173!2d43.147162!2m1!2b1!3e0)

-or-

[Embed Link](https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m73!1m12!1m3!1d1472548.9575794793!2d-72.8191002664707!3d43.87505426780168!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!4m58!3e0!4m5!1s0x0%3A0xa58b3d6041ba69f8!2sGuilford%20Welcome%20Center!3m2!1d42.8120069!2d-72.56614689999999!4m3!3m2!1d43.3893165!2d-72.40772249999999!4m5!1s0x4cb52e78df455c83%3A0xb6946ec850907db8!2s130%20Lower%20Michigan%20Road%2C%20Pittsfield%2C%20VT%2005762!3m2!1d43.76898!2d-72.815214!4m4!1s0x0%3A0xea2de48bba82cc86!3m2!1d44.042544!2d-72.6046997!4m5!1s0x0%3A0x6bb602ed58bf4413!2sJay%20Peak%20Resort!3m2!1d44.9379515!2d-72.5045433!4m5!1s0x4cb392aaa4333a07%3A0x160aef1559868340!2sDolly%20Copp%20Campground%20Rd%2C%20Gorham%2C%20NH%2003581!3m2!1d44.335842199999995!2d-71.21837339999999!4m5!1s0x4cb392684201a94d%3A0xfa4a6f490a05429d!2sMt%20Washington%20Auto%20Road%2C%201%20Mount%20Washington%20Auto%20Road%2C%20Gorham%2C%20NH%2003581!3m2!1d44.288384099999995!2d-71.22459599999999!4m5!1s0x4cb38e798f42c3d9%3A0xc3b88e4dac01db12!2sMt%20Washington!3m2!1d44.270585399999995!2d-71.3032723!4m5!1s0x89e2a7fa444124d5%3A0xe3ed24b6f864eba0!2sWells%2C%20ME!3m2!1d43.322232899999996!2d-70.5805209!4m5!1s0x89e2ba813e828c71%3A0x8cdf74380f6a933d!2sLibby's%20Oceanside%20Camp%2C%20York%20Street%2C%20York%2C%20ME!3m2!1d43.147162!2d-70.626173!5e1!3m2!1sen!2sus!4v1472497940601)

I have looked at the API's and I can't find anything that accepts or would decode the PB (what is this? it's not a protocol buffer). So far this is as far as I've got:

```
//php
$pb_array = explode('!', $pb);
foreach($pb_array as $key => $value){
    echo "$key - $value<br/>";
}
```

===

`1 - 1m73
2 - 1m12
3 - 1m3
4 - 1d1472548.9575794793
5 - 2d-72.8191002664707
6 - 3d43.87505426780168
7 - 2m3
8 - 1f0
9 - 2f0
10 - 3f0
11 - 3m2
12 - 1i1024
13 - 2i768
14 - 4f13.1
15 - 4m58
16 - 3e0
17 - 4m5
18 - 1s0x0%3A0xa58b3d6041ba69f8
19 - 2sGuilford+Welcome+Center
20 - 3m2
21 - 1d42.8120069
22 - 2d-72.56614689999999
23 - 4m3
24 - 3m2
25 - 1d43.3893165
26 - 2d-72.40772249999999
27 - 4m5
28 - 1s0x4cb52e78df455c83%3A0xb6946ec850907db8
29 - 2s130+Lower+Michigan+Road%2C+Pittsfield%2C+VT+05762
30 - 3m2
31 - 1d43.76898
32 - 2d-72.815214
33 - 4m4
34 - 1s0x0%3A0xea2de48bba82cc86
35 - 3m2
36 - 1d44.042544
37 - 2d-72.6046997
38 - 4m5
39 - 1s0x0%3A0x6bb602ed58bf4413
40 - 2sJay+Peak+Resort
41 - 3m2
42 - 1d44.9379515
43 - 2d-72.5045433
44 - 4m5
45 - 1s0x4cb392aaa4333a07%3A0x160aef1559868340
46 - 2sDolly+Copp+Campground+Rd%2C+Gorham%2C+NH+03581
47 - 3m2
48 - 1d44.335842199999995
49 - 2d-71.21837339999999
50 - 4m5
51 - 1s0x4cb392684201a94d%3A0xfa4a6f490a05429d
52 - 2sMt+Washington+Auto+Road%2C+1+Mount+Washington+Auto+Road%2C+Gorham%2C+NH+03581
53 - 3m2
54 - 1d44.288384099999995
55 - 2d-71.22459599999999
56 - 4m5
57 - 1s0x4cb38e798f42c3d9%3A0xc3b88e4dac01db12
58 - 2sMt+Washington
59 - 3m2
60 - 1d44.270585399999995
61 - 2d-71.3032723
62 - 4m5
63 - 1s0x89e2a7fa444124d5%3A0xe3ed24b6f864eba0
64 - 2sWells%2C+ME
65 - 3m2
66 - 1d43.322232899999996
67 - 2d-70.5805209
68 - 4m5
69 - 1s0x89e2ba813e828c71%3A0x8cdf74380f6a933d
70 - 2sLibby's+Oceanside+Camp%2C+York+Street%2C+York%2C+ME
71 - 3m2
72 - 1d43.147162
73 - 2d-70.626173
74 - 5e1
75 - 3m2
76 - 1sen
77 - 2sus
78 - 4v1472497940601`

The closest hints I could find are from this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18413193/how-do-i-decode-encode-the-url-parameters-for-the-new-google-maps). I will keep looking but I'm stuck.

I'm trying to create an API based solution that has an input of one of these URL's and returns a GeoJSON.

Comment: I'm potentially getting somewhere.... see my [Gist](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/1477f387e1433ed190d3cbfbf9bfec59) where I'm making progress getting the datapoints. It's pretty "hacky"

Comment: My suggestion would be to capture the origin, destination and waypoints, then use either the [Directions Web Service](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/) or the [Google Maps Javascript API v3 DirectionsService](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/directions) to get the polylines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> would decode the PB (what is this? it's not a protocol buffer)

For the record, because this overflow question keeps popping up on google results: it **is** [a protocol buffer](https://github.com/marin-m/pbtk/wiki/Protobuf-URL). PB litteraly stands for **p**rotocol **b**uffer.

It's just a different ASCII encoding (a compact URL encoding reminiscent of the binary encoding, not the usual JSON-like text encoding. When you squint at it it's not that much different than torrent's structure encoding), and Google doesn't provide us the `.proto` file.

For each field:

- first character is the id (identifies the field according to the corresponding `.proto` file)
- second character is the type of the field

  - m is for message
  - s is for string
  - i, j, u, v are for various type of ints
  - f, d are for floating points
  - e is for enum
- the rest is the payload

So to unpack the fields you're seeing (even if we don't have the `.proto` file):

- `1m73` message of type 1, containing 73 elements (the whole message set)

  - `1m12` submessage of type 1, contains 12 elements (probably information about the view box in the map box)

    - `1m3` sub-sub-message type 1, contains 3 elements (probably map coordinates)

      - `1d1472548.9575794793` first double field (probably zoom level)
      - `2d-72.8191002664707` second double field (probably longitude)
      - `3d43.87505426780168` third double field (probably latitude)
    - `2m3` second sub-sub-sub message (no idea given that it's not filled. Maybe a starting point if you code a route instead of a single point ?)

      - `1f0`, `2f0`, `3f0`  the three members, currently just zero
    - `3m2` third block (looks like a screen resolution)

      - `1i1024`, `2i768` : 1024x768 ? (and probably the omited field 3 would have been the color depth if present ??)
      - `4f13.1` no idea, but it's a float
  - `4m58` next message with 58 elements (to me it looks like a bunch of POI that we need to display in the box)

    - `3e0` an enum, set to zero (this one would be completely impossible to interpret without a proto or without experimenting, as you need the list of enums)
    - `4m5` five more elements probably a map poi
      - `1s0x0%3A0xa58b3d6041ba69f8` string '0x0:0xa58b3d6041ba69f8', note the use of Url_encoded character. In turn it looks like a pair of hex numbers, maybe a GUID ?
      - `2sGuilford+Welcome+Center` string, the name with plus instead of blank (like most URLs)
      - `3m2` two elements to come
      - `1d42.8120069` and `2d-72.56614689999999` doubles probably map coordinates
    - `4m3` again a message of type 4 in this level, so probably another poi
      - `3m2`, `1d43.3893165`, `2d-72.40772249999999` but this one only specifies coordinates, and nothing else
    - `4m5` another poi
      - `1s0x4cb52e78df455c83%3A0xb6946ec850907db8` different pair of hex, GUID

      ...you got the idea...
  - `5e1` another bunch of information probably general settings

    - `3m2` this setting is a message (and looks like a locale)

      - `1sen`, `2sus` locale is en_US
    - `4v1472497940601` some other large number...

Note: the original proto that Google doesn't show us, is probably a single multi level structure. Thus, the sub-sub-message ID don't have always the same meaning: they aren't global ID, but ID within the parent message.

- inside a sub message ID 1 (view box ?), the sub-sub message 3 seems to be resolution.
- inside a sub message ID 4 (POIs ?), the sub-ID 3 isn't even a message but some enum
- inside a sub message ID 5 (parameters), the sub-sub message 3 is a locale

Answer (score 0):

Well, here's my sloppy but working solution. My needs required GeoJSON, but others can use the google maps service to get the desired output once you have the lat/lng array.

```
$embed = '<iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m73!1m12!1m3!1d1472548.9575794793!2d-72.8191002664707!3d43.87505426780168!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!4m58!3e0!4m5!1s0x0%3A0xa58b3d6041ba69f8!2sGuilford+Welcome+Center!3m2!1d42.8120069!2d-72.56614689999999!4m3!3m2!1d43.3893165!2d-72.40772249999999!4m5!1s0x4cb52e78df455c83%3A0xb6946ec850907db8!2s130+Lower+Michigan+Road%2C+Pittsfield%2C+VT+05762!3m2!1d43.76898!2d-72.815214!4m4!1s0x0%3A0xea2de48bba82cc86!3m2!1d44.042544!2d-72.6046997!4m5!1s0x0%3A0x6bb602ed58bf4413!2sJay+Peak+Resort!3m2!1d44.9379515!2d-72.5045433!4m5!1s0x4cb392aaa4333a07%3A0x160aef1559868340!2sDolly+Copp+Campground+Rd%2C+Gorham%2C+NH+03581!3m2!1d44.335842199999995!2d-71.21837339999999!4m5!1s0x4cb392684201a94d%3A0xfa4a6f490a05429d!2sMt+Washington+Auto+Road%2C+1+Mount+Washington+Auto+Road%2C+Gorham%2C+NH+03581!3m2!1d44.288384099999995!2d-71.22459599999999!4m5!1s0x4cb38e798f42c3d9%3A0xc3b88e4dac01db12!2sMt+Washington!3m2!1d44.270585399999995!2d-71.3032723!4m5!1s0x89e2a7fa444124d5%3A0xe3ed24b6f864eba0!2sWells%2C+ME!3m2!1d43.322232899999996!2d-70.5805209!4m5!1s0x89e2ba813e828c71%3A0x8cdf74380f6a933d!2sLibby&#39;s+Oceanside+Camp%2C+York+Street%2C+York%2C+ME!3m2!1d43.147162!2d-70.626173!5e1!3m2!1sen!2sus!4v1472497940601" width="600" height="450" frameborder="0" style="border:0" allowfullscreen></iframe>';

$array = array();
preg_match( '/src="([^"]*)"/i', $embed, $array ) ;
list($pre, $pb) = split("pb=", $array[1]);

if($pb == "" || strpos($pb, "!") === false)
    die(json_encode(array("success"=>false)));

//echo "PB Extracted:<br>";
//echo $pb;
///echo "<br><br>Decode:<br/>";
$pb_array = explode('!', $pb);

$coords = array();
$address;$addressHex;
$results = array();
foreach($pb_array as $key => $value){
    //uncomment to debug output
    //echo "$key - $value<br/>";

    if($value == "3m2" || $value == "2m2"){
        //3m2 seems to be the divider of these 'places'
        if(count($coords) != 3) //don't add the center of map data (3 coordinates [height, lng, lat])
            array_push($results, array("coords"=>$coords,"address"=>$address,"addressHex"=>$addressHex));
        $coords = array(); //reset array
    }else{
        $type = substr($value, 1, 1);
        $stype = substr($value, 0, 2);
        $value = substr($value, 2);
        //echo "$type - $value<br/>";
        if($type == "d"){
            //Found Lat,Lng
            array_push($coords, $value);
        }else if($stype == "2s"){
            //Address
            $address = $value;
        }else if($stype == "1s"){
            //Address Encoded in some way
            $addressHex = $value;
        }
    }
}

//echo "<br><br>Google Result<br/>";
//echo json_encode($results);


//echo "<br><br>Mapbox API:<br/>";
$waypoints = array();
for($i=0;$i<count($results);$i++){
    if(count($results[$i]["coords"])){
        $lat = $results[$i]["coords"][0];
        $lng = $results[$i]["coords"][1];
        array_push($waypoints, "$lng%2C$lat");
    }
}
$waypoints = implode("%3B", $waypoints); //convert to string

$mapbox_api_key = "pk.eyJ1I.....";
$url = "https://api.mapbox.com/directions/v5/mapbox/driving/$waypoints.json?steps=false&alternatives=false&overview=full&geometries=geojson&access_token=$mapbox_api_key";

//echo "<br><br>Mapbox Response:<br/>";
$response = file_get_contents($url); 

$json = json_decode($response,true);
//echo "<br><br>Mapbox Geometry:<br/>";
$coordinates = $json["routes"][0]["geometry"]["coordinates"];

$geojson = (array("type"=>"FeatureCollection","features"=>array(array("type"=>"Feature","geometry"=>array("type"=>"LineString","coordinates"=>$coordinates),"properties"=>array()))));

echo json_encode(array("success"=>true, "geojson"=>$geojson));
```