# How do I get the address and coordinates given this google place url?

Tags: google-maps

`https://www.google.com/maps/place/@/data=!4m2!3m1!1s0x88c2cdd22ab04385:0xf12ec367be629fbc`
How do I get the address and coordinates given this google place url?

Answer (score 1):

From the answer to these related questions:

- [how do i decode/encode the url parameters for the new google maps?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18413193/how-do-i-decode-encode-the-url-parameters-for-the-new-google-maps)
- [Decoding the Google Maps embedded parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47017387/decoding-the-google-maps-embedded-parameters)

```
https://www.google.com/maps/place/@/data=
!4m2
!3m1
!1s0x88c2cdd22ab04385:0xf12ec367be629fbc
```

> ftid is 0x88c2cdd22ab04385:0xf12ec367be629fbc

There are no coordinates in the provided URL.  That is only a ftid for [Jimmy John's](https://google.com/maps?ftid=0x88c2cdd22ab04385:0xf12ec367be629fbc)

If you decode the URL retrieved from [**that** redirected request](https://www.google.com/maps/place/Jimmy+John's/@27.9371703,-82.2956035,17z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m5!3m4!1s0x88c2cdd22ab04385:0xf12ec367be629fbc!8m2!3d27.9371703!4d-82.2934148):

> `https://www.google.com/maps/place/Jimmy+John's/@27.9371703,-82.2956035,17z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m5!3m4!1s0x88c2cdd22ab04385:0xf12ec367be629fbc!8m2!3d27.9371703!4d-82.2934148`

you can get coordinates (note, they are not the coordinates after the `@`, they are decoded from the last two entries in the URL):

> 27.9371703,-82.2934148

[fiddle showing location](https://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/3Luvtxhw/5/)

[image: screenshot showing decoded location]

Comment: Thank you @geocodezip, the answer was in the second related question you suggested.