# How to decode a pb string from a url parameter

Tags: protocol-buffers, decode

I have the following value that has been passed by google in a request header. Some research shows that pb stands for Protofile Buffer and is a binary string format for some data that is being passed. How can I decode this string to see a human-readable version of the data?

```
&pb=!1m2!1y5180949545401667117!2y10222232094831998944!2m1!2i10!3e1!4m6!3b1!4b1!5b1!6b1!7b1!20b1!5m2!1sjDZuZKnJB8uu5NoPkJ-GyA8!7e81'
```

Comment: Your question lacks detail, any attempt to solve this problem for yourself and is likely to be downvoted or closed. Although `pb` suggests protocol buffers (sic.), the value does not appear to be a protocol buffer message. Googling shows that `pb` appears in Google Maps Embed API as a query string parameter. Is that where it's arising? If so, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47017387/decoding-the-google-maps-embedded-parameters and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18413193/how-do-i-decode-encode-the-url-parameters-for-the-new-google-maps/34275131#34275131